# I Try to export data from Firebase to XLSX using kotlin but whe i run the program nothing happend

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, apache-poi

I Try to export data from Firebase to XLSX using kotlin but whe i run the program nothing happend no error at my code but i can't find the export file this my code

```
val db =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aktivitas")
        btndownload.setOnClickListener{
            val query_kegiatan = db.orderByChild("aktivitas")

            query_kegiatan.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val workbook = XSSFWorkbook()
                    val sheet = workbook.createSheet("Aktivitas")

                    var rownum = 0
                    for(item in snapshot.children){
                        val row = sheet.createRow(rownum++)
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(item.child("bagian").value as String)
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(item.child("barang").value as String)
                        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(item.child("jumlah").value as String)
                        row.createCell(3).setCellValue(item.child("keterangan").value as String)

                       val save = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"aktivitas.xlsx")
                        val fos = FileOutputStream(save)
                        workbook.write(fos)

                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            })

        }
```

i try to export data from firebase to xlsx using kotlin using apache.poi library i did't see any error i expecting to export the data to xlsx

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Aside from that,
"nothing happend" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work?

Comment: i got this form log chat at com.example.proyek_informatika.Menu$onCreate$2$1.onDataChange(Menu.kt:101)

Comment: and   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already
                                                                                                     at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:215)